# How to perform a sentiment analysis on a csv file

Tags: python, data-mining, analysis, sentiment-analysis

I have a CSV file which contains comments, how would i run a sentiment analysis on this file? Would preferably wish to use python. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. you get training data
2. you implement the classification algorithm
3. perform sentiment analysis
4. get rich!

Comment: Erm could i have a bit more information on how to implement this !

Comment: Just do it. Start coding. Don't ask abstract questions that cannot be answered (except if we'd write a whole book "sentiment analysis 101" for you, which we won't).